# Which graphs, with at least one edge have the the property that every edge is a bridge?

Tags: graph-theory

> Which graphs, with at least one edge have the the property that every edge is a bridge?

I know trees are one. Do you have more examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, a forest (collection of trees) are the only such graphs.

If there was a cycle, then the edges of the cycle would not be bridges.

Comment: Oh right, What about paths? I meant to say paths. Is a forest a path?

Comment: @Mark: A path is a tree, which by definition, is a forest too.

Comment: @Mark "Is a forest a path?" Not sure what you meant, but a path is a particular example of a tree, and trees are special cases of forests with just $1$ component.